# How to convert python date format to 10-digit date format for mysql?

Tags: python

how to convert python date format to 10 digit date format for mysql

example:
date in python -> 11-05-09

to something like 1239992972 (10 digit)

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can use the time module's strptime - you pass in a string time (e.g. 11-05-09) and a format and it will return a struct_time, which you can get the numerical value from (by calling time.mktime on the returned struct_time). See the [docs for `time.strptime`](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strptime) for further details.

Answer (score 2):

If it is a datetime obj, you can do:

```
import time
time.mktime(datetime_obj.timetuple())
```

If not:

```
time.mktime(time.strptime("11-05-09", "%d-%m-%y"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use time.strptime() to convert the date into a time tuple, and then time.mktime() (or calendar.timegm()) to convert that into a floating point time. You'll probably need to truncate it to an integer after.

```
tm = time.strptime('11-05-09', '%d-%m-%y')
time = time.mktime(tm)
time_int = int(time)
```

http://docs.python.org/library/time.html

Comment: your format and date string are swapped, and there's no %f identifier

Answer (score 0):

You can use [easy_date](https://github.com/ralphavalon/easy_date) to make it easy:

```
import date_converter
timestamp = date_converter.string_to_timestamp('11-05-09','%d-%m-%y')
```